# Pointer comparison causing errors

Tags: c

I'm trying to make a simple function that searches a chosen column for the first instance of a value, and then have it return the row it's in. This would search in a predefined struct called "SPREADSHEET". However, I'm having some major problems.

I'm getting error "incompatable type for argument 1 of memcpy" and a couple of other errors. Here's my code:

```
// Searches down the specified column for a row which contains text.
// The search starts at row number rowNum;
// The result is the row number (where the first row is numbered 0).
// If the text is not found, the result is -1.
int SS_FindRow(SPREADSHEET *ss, int colNum, char *text, int startNum) {
    if (debug)
        fprintf(stderr, "DEBUG: Call to SS_FindRow(--,%d,%s,%d)\n",
            colNum, text, startNum);
    // TO BE COMPLETED!
    SPREADSHEET read;
    memcpy(read,ss,sizeof(ss));
    int i;
    for(i = startNum; i < MAXROWS; i++) {
        if(strcmp(&read.contents[i][colNum],text)==0)
            return i;
    }
    return -1;
}
```

I'm really stumped as to what could be causing this. Running the program and the no matter what my input is the if statement will never succeed. Help?

Comment: try `memcpy(&read,ss,sizeof(*ss));`

Comment: "incompatable type for argument 1 of memcpy" means it shall be `memcpy(&read, ss, sizeof(ss))`. And what about other errors?

Comment: @starrify: `sizeof *ss`.

Comment: @Deduplicator yes, i edit it.

Comment: And thanks to Bluepixy my code magically works. How could I forget the asterisk? D'oh.

Comment: Your code is not modifying the contents of parameter ss, so why copy it locally?  So this line: if(strcmp(&read.contents[i][colNum],text)==0) should be if(strcmp(ss->contents[i][colNum],text)==0)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
int SS_FindRow(SPREADSHEET *ss, int colNum, char *text, int startNum) {
                           ^

memcpy(read,ss,sizeof(ss));
                      ^^
```

You probably want the `sizeof` a `SPREADSHEET`, not a pointer to one. The easiest solution here is to use `sizeof(read)` instead.

Also, the first parameter to `memcpy` needs to be where to copy to. So you want `&read` (the address of `read`), not `read` (the value of `read`).

Answer (score 1):

Syntax of memcpy() is
`void *memcpy(void *str1, const void *str2, size_t n)`

`read` must be a pointer pointing to a memory location, then you can use `memcpy()`

Or use `&read` in `memcpy()`.